# How to display the components based on category selection

Tags: html, vue.js

Here I have written a Vue.js code. So here I have multiple templates so for multiple templates I have written multiple components.

So now I have to display each components based on selected category.

For example in the select option if i select `single family homes` then `step2` component should display if i select `real state` then `step3` components should displayed.

And also how to display the entered value in preview page

```js
*vuejs*
<script>
Vue.component(
    'step1',
    {
        template: '#step1',
        props: [
            'currentStep',
            'step1'
        ]
    }
);

Vue.component(
    'step2',
    {
        template: '#step2',
        props: [
            'currentStep',
            'step2'
        ]
    }
);

Vue.component(
    'step3', 
    {
        template: '#step3',
        props: [
            'currentStep',
            'step1',
            'step2'
        ]
    }
);

Vue.component(
    'step4', 
    {
        template: '#step4',
        props: [
            'currentStep',
            'step1',
            'step2'
        ]
    }
);

var app = new Vue(
    {
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            currentStep: 1,
            step1: {
                category: '',
                title: '',
                address: '',
                city:'',
                state:'',
                Zip:'',
                price:'',
                description:'',
            },
            step2: {
                bedrooms_p: '',
                bathrooms_p: '',
                square_ft_p: '',
                lot_size_p: '',
                total_rooms_p: '',
                stories_p: '',
                year_built_p: '',
                h_o_a_p: '',
                garages_p: '',
                basement_p: '',
                roof_p: '',
                exterior_p: '',
                cooling_p: '',
                heating_p: '',
                schools_p: '',
                image_p: '',
                image2_p: '',
                image3_p: '',
                image4_p: '',
            },
        },
        ready: function() {
            console.log('ready');
        },
        methods: {
            goToStep: function(step) {
                this.currentStep ++;
            },
            stepsback: function(step) {
                this.currentStep --;
            },
        }
    }
);
</script>
```

```html
<select>
    <option>single family homes</option>
    <option>real state</option>
    <option>IT industry</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution, although it has arbitrary values, as your example code is not complete.

```
<step1 
    currentStep="some_value" 
    step1="another_value"
    v-if="'step1' === select_value"
/>
<step2 
    currentStep="some_value" 
    step2="another_value"
    v-if="'step2' === select_value"
/>
<step3 
    currentStep="some_value" 
    step1="another_value" 
    step2="yet_another_value"
    v-if="'step3' === select_value"
/>
<step4 
    currentStep="some_value" 
    step1="another_value" 
    step2="yet_another_value"
    v-if="'step4' === select_value"
/>
```

The variable `select_value` is the selected value of the `select` element in your HTML. To use it you have to bind the value of the select in the Vue model.

For example you could use inside your Vue app something like that:

```
var app = new Vue(
    {
        el: '#app',
        data: function () {
            return {
                select_value: ''
                // rest of your data properties
            }
        }
        // rest of your component functionality
    }
);
```

and then change your `select` element to something like that:

```
<select v-model="select_value">
    <option value="step1">single family homes</option>
    <option value="step2">real state</option>
    <option value="step3">IT industry</option>
    <option value="step4">Some Other Option</option>
</select>
```

By making those changes you will have at the end the result you need.

Comment: <step1 
    currentStep="some_value" 
    step1="another_value"
    v-if="'step1' === select_value"
/> this should i write in template

Comment: @AsadAhmedkhan yes. This is how you control the visibility of the elements in Vue. Just keep in mind that the `select_value` should be bound to your Vue instance! Otherwise will not work. For more details see my example in my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try out to give a value to your options then using [dynamic component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) :

```html
<select v-model="select_value">
    <option value="1">single family homes</option>
    <option value="2">real state</option>
    <option value="3">IT industry</option>
    <option value="4">Some Other Option</option>
</select>
```

and :

```html
<component currentStep="some_value" step1="another_value"  step2="yet_another_value" :is="`step${select_value}`" />
```

Comment: Your approach is very nice and more clear, but in your solution how could you handle the case of multiple props? I mean, in his example, he has some components with only two props, while some other have 3.

Comment: your solution is good but I don't like the repetitive v-if, you could use [v-switch-case](https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-switch-case) or dynamic component

Comment: in order to make the code shorter you could pass all of them

Comment: Yes you are right about the `v-if` but for a starter user like this one, I guess approaches like `component` or `v-switch-case` may work like a **black box** :) Thank you for all your mentions :)

Comment: Thank you sir. Its look nice and I have tried. But here above  I have given select option . So if we Have a category in our database like " single family home, real state  etc " How to achieve that

Comment: you're welcome, I don't understand your issue

Comment: <select v-model="select_value">
    <option value="1">single family homes</option>
    <option value="2">real state</option>
    <option value="3">IT industry</option>
    <option value="4">Some Other Option</option>
</select> using this select option we are prompting components instead of this if we are accessing the categories from database then how we can achieve